# show current power consumption Cisco 3650 IOS 3.07.04E

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, power

What command can I issue to see the current power (POE and System Power) on a Cisco 3650 Switch running IOS 3.07.04E.

`Sh Env Power` #shows me power supplies, not usage.

`Sh Power Inline` #show me the inline power consumption and usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power consumption on Cisco's new 3650 platform is very variable. It all depends on traffic flow, PoE and utilization of ports on the switch model. Cisco has made a Power Consumption table, which shows different usage for different scenarios. It's available via the provided link. Picture is for future reference. Remember to add your inline power of Access points, IP phones or cameras.

It is not possible to show the live power consumption via IOS.

Source: [Look for table 12](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3650-series-switches/datasheet-c78-729449.html)

[image]

Comment: Hi Cown, Thanks for the response. I am however looking for the command that shows the current power consumption and availability.

Comment: @Max That is not possible, since the power consumption changes constantly with the IMIX flow. The only way you can get the actual current consumption is to use third party electrical power consumption meter connected to the switch power supply. That is also why Cisco has provided a Weighted average.

Comment: That's a shame. I was looking for an equivelant to the "sh power available" command availabe on the 4506 series, which shoes current and available power consumpion.

Comment: @Max Yeah it's pretty weird Cisco did not implement the option to check the live consumption on the 3650 series. I guess it could be a future option to be added?

Comment: @Max I just tried to enable EnergyWise with the following commands: Global config: `energywise domain Cisco security shared-secret test1234` Interface config: `int range gi1/0/1-24` <enter> `energywise` <enter> - I then tried to check usage: `sh energywise usage children` gave som totals, but it looks like the max for the switch is always 250W used. But the Access points give correct usage: `Gi1/0/1     APXXXX.XXXX.XXXX 6.7  (W)`

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any 3650's at the moment but I have a 3850 running 3.7.3E.
Looks like it will tell you the actual consumption.

```
Switch#show power inline police

Module   Available     Used     Remaining
          (Watts)     (Watts)    (Watts)
------   ---------   --------   ---------
1          1800.0      215.6      1584.4
Interface Admin  Oper       Admin      Oper       Cutoff Oper
          State  State      Police     Police     Power  Power
--------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ------ -----
Gi1/0/1   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/2   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/3   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/4   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/5   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/6   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/7   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/8   auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/9   auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/10  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.5
Gi1/0/11  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.6
Gi1/0/12  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/13  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.6
Gi1/0/14  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/15  auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/16  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/17  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/18  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/19  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.6
Gi1/0/20  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/21  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/22  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.6
Gi1/0/23  auto   on         none       n/a        n/a    2.7
Gi1/0/24  auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Gi1/0/25  auto   off        none       n/a        n/a    n/a
Switch#show power inline gigabitEthernet 1/0/20 detail
 Interface: Gi1/0/20
 Inline Power Mode: auto
 Operational status: on
 Device Detected: yes
 Device Type: Ieee PD
 IEEE Class: 3
 Discovery mechanism used/configured: Ieee and Cisco
 Police: off

 Power Allocated
 Admin Value: 60.0
 Power drawn from the source: 15.4
 Power available to the device: 15.4

 Actual consumption
 Measured at the port: 2.7
 Maximum Power drawn by the device since powered on: 3.6

 Absent Counter: 0
 Over Current Counter: 0
 Short Current Counter: 0
 Invalid Signature Counter: 0
 Power Denied Counter: 0

 Power Negotiation Used: None
 LLDP Power Negotiation --Sent to PD--      --Rcvd from PD--
   Power Type:          -                    -
   Power Source:        -                    -
   Power Priority:      -                    -
   Requested Power(W):  -                    -
   Allocated Power(W):  -                    -

Four-Pair PoE Supported: Yes
Spare Pair Power Enabled: No
Four-Pair PD Architecture: N/A
Switch#show ver
Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.07.03.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
```